# Accessing database from PHP in mixed PHP/Java EE server-side environment

Tags: java, php, jakarta-ee

is there a way to use PHP for database manipulation (i.e. a web application) in a Java EE environment. All the database interactions on the Java EE are done through JPA (Eclipselink) and I am wondering is there a way to use PHP directly, or do you need to always call stateless EJBs from PHP, which in turn call JPA?

The main issue is JPA "caching", i.e. the fact that JPA has tons of logic in itself, and also memory structures for pulled-out data, so if PHP modified something directly in the database, JPA would get out of sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, you can take a look at the PHP/Java bridge project:

http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/